# Linking to an external site from a Jupyter notebook running on server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I'm writing up example notebooks for my organization, which has a hosted server to run Jupyter notebooks. In a markdown cell I'm trying to include links to external examples, but Jupyter seems to parse these as links internal to the server. As in, I'm trying to create a link like this:

[link text goes here] (www.link_site.com)

which does create a link, but clicking it tries to bring you to a location like jupyterserver/directory_of_notebook/www.link_site.com, at which point Jupyter throws up a 404 because that location doesn't exist.

There must be a simple way to point to an external site, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: just use HTML, ie `<a href="www.link_site.com">link text goes here</a>`

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem - whether you create the link using HTML rather than markdown, it still points to a location on the server, rather that to the website I'm looking for.

Comment: does this happen even if you prefix `https://`?

Comment: No, that was all I needed. Thank you!